# Problem connecting the ROS file

Tags: vmware, ros

I installed a VMware virtual machine on Windows 11, then installed Ubuntu in order to launch the ROS operating system. I found a ready-made project at the link - https://github.com/SakshayMahna/Machine-Learning-in-ROS. There is also a video for it - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sY0pA9OfD5Y&t=298s.

As soon as I run the file lane_follower.py, as it is said in the video at the 4th minute, I get this error, that is, the file 'prius msgs' is not visible in the connected files 'lane_follower.py', although I have already tried everything, changed the position file in the directories, in 'lane_follower.py' indicated the direct path to the file 'prius msgs', How can I deal with this problem?

```
:/opt/ros/noetic/share/MLinROS/car_ws/src/perception/scripts$ python3   line_follower.ру  
Traceback (most recent call last):  
File "lane_follower.py", line 5, in <module>  
from prius_msgs.msg import Control  
Module Not Found Error: No module named 'prius msgs'
```